# A service installation section in this INF is invalid - Trying to install USB Phone driver

Tags: windows, driver, windows-11

I'm encountering an issue when trying to install the driver for my Android phone automatically. When I connect my phone, a driver with a question mark is displayed. Upon clicking "Update driver," I receive an error message stating, "A service installation section in this INF is invalid."

As a temporary solution, I can update the driver by browsing and selecting it manually. I notice that there are two drivers available: "MTP Device" and "MTP USB Device." Whenever I choose "MTP Device," I always encounter the "INF Invalid" error. However, selecting "MTP USB Device" installs the driver successfully.

My goal is to have the "MTP USB Device" driver selected automatically whenever I connect any phone, and I would like to remove the "MTP Device" driver from my system entirely.

Here are the steps I have already taken in an attempt to resolve the issue:

- Executed the following commands in Command Prompt:

  - `sfc /scannow`
  - `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`
  - `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`
  - `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
- Uninstalled all USB drivers using DriverStoreExplorer.v0.11.92.
- Uninstalled all USB drivers, including the Google driver, with RevoUninstaller_Portable.
- Updated all drivers using DriverEasy.
- Open Device Manager,Right-click on the problematic driver entry and select Uninstall ( There is no "Delete the driver software for this device" option. )
- Ensured that my Windows system is up to date.
- Do system update.

Unfortunately, none of these attempts have been successful in resolving the driver error. In the Event Viewer, I encountered the following error message:

- Error: 5/25/2023 4:14:17 AM, WPD-ClassInstaller, Event ID 25088, Driver Installation.

  - It was not possible to install drivers for the device USB\VID_2717&PID_FF40&REV_0419. Error code 0xe0000217.
- Warning   5/25/2023 4:14:17 AM    DeviceSetupManager  122 None

  - Access to drivers on Windows Update was blocked by policy

My system details are as follows:

- Windows Version:

  - OS Name: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
  - Version: 10.0.22624 Build 22624

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue and achieving automatic driver selection for the "MTP USB Device" driver when connecting my phone. Thank you in advance for your help.